# highcharts draggabble pie in combo chart

Tags: highcharts

There is a demo pie combo chart in the link below. How to make the pie draggable(drag and drop) so that it will not cover other parts of the chart sometimes?

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Combination chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s;
                if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                    s = ''+
                        this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' fruits';
                } else {
                    s = ''+
                        this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                }
                return s;
            }
        },
        labels: {
            items: [{
                html: 'Total fruit consumption',
                style: {
                    left: '40px',
                    top: '8px',
                    color: 'black'
                }
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'John',
            data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
        }, {
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Average',
            data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                fillColor: 'white'
            }
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Total consumption',
            data: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                y: 13,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Jane's color
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                y: 23,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // John's color
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                y: 19,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Joe's color
            }],
            center: [100, 40],
            size: 100,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Regards,
minfunfun

Comment: that jsfiddle doesn't work for me ?

Comment: The same code comes from this link: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to split chart into two - one with columns/lines/etc and second one as pie chart which will have position absolute and all you need to do is add drag and drop to pie container.

Comment: I am a newbie in highcharts. Is there an example or link to show how to add drag and drop to a pie container? Thx.

Comment: I don't have such example, but it should be like simple drag&drop (like jQuery drag and drop) - just make pie chart as single chart, add drag and drop to that pie and that's should be it. IF wouldn't be able to achieve that - show jsFiddle with your tries, I will try to help.

Comment: I tried to use  jQuery drag and drop. It's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".highcharts-series").draggable();
```

it will make all your series draggable